# How to compare times in different time zones in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date, time

I have this date that which is in timezone offset format that I need to convert to UTC format. 
For example:

date1 = 2017-07-13T17:13:12-04:00

date2_utc = 2017-07-13 21:13:12 UTC

I need to compare if those two date are same date. Or If I can convert date1 to UTC then i can compare those two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I need to compare if those two date are same date.

You don't have to convert them, `==` will take care of the time zone:

```
t1 = Time.parse('2017-07-13T17:13:12-04:00')
#=> 2017-07-13 17:13:12 -0400

t2 = Time.parse('2017-07-13 21:13:12 UTC')
#=> 2017-07-13 21:13:12 UTC

t1 == t2
#=> true
```

Comment: damn. Why I didn't think of it! Thank you v much.

Comment: @KiranGautam after all, they represent the same point in time, i.e. `t1.to_i == t2.to_i`